# Attempting to make an algorithm that translates to different numerical bases

Tags: protostuff

I'd like to make an algorithm, f, that takes `a`, `x` and `y`, and returns `b` in base `y` as opposed to `a` in base `x`. I can't seem to make sense of how to do this, and I've made multiple attempts. How does one go about that?

```py
def f(a, x, y):
    pass  # should convert (a in base x) to (b in base y)
```